# Setting the Google Chrome Security and Privacy settings using Group Policy on Active Directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension, group-policy

I am trying to enforce the "**Enhanced Security**" feature on Google Chrome Browser as against the "**Standard Security**" settings on the Privacy and Security setting stab and wondering how this can be achieved from Active Directory Group Policy Management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded the adms for Chrome?

Once downloaded and installed, the setting will be located here:
**User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Google > Google Chrome > Safe browsing settings**
[image: settings image]

Check the [details](https://techexpert.tips/windows/gpo-enable-safe-browsing-google-chrome)